# How to avoid Terraform's repeated in-place updates of AWS autoscaling policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

More specifically, `adjustment_type` keeps getting (seemingly) updated on each `terraform plan`. Why is that and can it be avoided?

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_autoscaling_policy.this will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "this" {
      + adjustment_type           = "ChangeInCapacity"
```

Here's autoscaling policy definition:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "this" {
  name                   = var.service_name # Same between `terraform` invocations.
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.this.name
  adjustment_type        = "ChangeInCapacity"
  policy_type            = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  # ASG merely serves as an EC2-ready-to-be-made-scalable, hence `false`.
  enabled = false
  target_tracking_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ASGAverageCPUUtilization"
    }
    target_value = 99.0
  }
}
```

- terraform 1.3.1
- terragrunt 0.40.2

Comment: not sure why it might be changing, but you can pass meta_data in the resource to ignore changes on a particular attribute of a resource https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes

Comment: What is your `aws_autoscaling_policy` definition?

Comment: @Marcin, I've added its definition. Do you see anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: I think you are seeing the behavior in [provider bug #18853](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18853)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hashicorp/aws` provider uses a single resource type `aws_autoscaling_policy` to represent both [Target Tracking Scaling Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html) and [Simple/Step Scaling Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html). Unfortunately each of these policy types expects a different subset of arguments, and (as discussed in [provider bug #18853](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18853)) there are some missing validation rules to catch when you use an argument that isn't appropriate for your selected type.

You are using `policy_type = "TargetTrackingScaling"`, but [Scaling Adjustment Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html#as-scaling-adjustment) are for step/simple scaling policies. Therefore I believe the AWS API is silently ignoring your `adjustment_type` value when creating/updating. When the AWS provider reads your policy back from the remote API during the refresh step, the API indicates that `adjustment_type` isn't set and so the AWS provider thinks it's changed outside of Terraform.

The best fix here would be for the provider to return an error if you use an argument that isn't appropriate for your `policy_type`, but in the meantime I suspect you can make this problem go away by leaving `adjustment_type` unset in your configuration, which should then make the desired state described by your configuration match the actual state of the remote object.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I think yours should be the accepted answer. I know, should've searched GH issues first. :)

Answer (score 2):

From the info in question there is no reason why it would change. Its possibile that you are experiencing "ghost" changes, which are known, long lasting TF issue, e.g. [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18311). You can try using [ignore_changes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes):

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "this" {
  name                   = var.service_name # Same between `terraform` invocations.
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.this.name
  adjustment_type        = "ChangeInCapacity"
  policy_type            = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  # ASG merely serves as an EC2-ready-to-be-made-scalable, hence `false`.
  enabled = false
  target_tracking_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ASGAverageCPUUtilization"
    }
    target_value = 99.0
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
       adjustment_type
    ]
  }

}
```